# "Ссёт" или "ссыт" – как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, обсценная-лексика

Моя подруга запрещает мне говорить "ссёт". Она утверждает, что никогда и нигде не слышала, чтобы так говорили. Утверждает, что только "ссыт" – правильный вариант произношения.

Как правильно?

Не надо думать, что я хулиганю. Это искренний вопрос, от чистого сердца!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я тоже не слышал, чтобы так говорили, но «встречаются также диалектный и просторечный варианты написания инфинитивов: [***ссять***,](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) *сцать*» (Викисловарь). Там как раз есть «ссёт».

Comment: Нашла: "Только покойник не ссыт в рукомойник". Не имея желания или возможности сходить по малой нужде в туалет, можно воспользоваться раковиной умывальника.

Жгучий глагол: Словарь народной фразеологии. — Зеленый век. В. Кузмич. 2000.